# Doing a school problem with files in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, fstream

So at school I'm solving C++ problems on Xcode but now I have to solve problems which include files and I don't know where to insert the input file. Here's an example:
“Rapunzel is in a tower of N meters high.  Flynn wants to climb it and travels M1 meters from sunrise to sunset, then from sunset to midnight another M2 meters. In how many days does Flynn arrive at Rapunzel?”

When I build the program the console disappears and I can't input anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("rapunzel.in");
    ofstream fout("rapunzel.out");
    long long unsigned N,M1,M2,m;
    fin >> N >> M1 >> M2;
    m = M1 + M2;
    if(N % m == 0)
        fout << N / m;
    else
        fout << N / m + 1;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to your code you're reading input from the file, not console

Comment: You have put the file names into your code: `rapunzel.in` and `rapunzel.out`. The program assumes these files to be in the directory that you run the program from. You can use absolute paths instead, as well (e.g. `/home/username/projectname/rapunzel.in`)